# style.fontWeight not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to to offer the user some control over the text display. I use document.getElementsByClassName to target all the selector inside a parent selector (has the class basic-text-frame). every thing run smoothly except myfunction8 (which control fontWeight)
and when delete the css it works
any ideas?

```js
function myFunction3() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-large";

  }
}

function myFunction4() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "large";

  }
}

function myFunction5() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "16px";

  }
}

function myFunction6() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "small";


  }
}

function myFunction7() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-small";
  }
}

function myFunction8() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "900";
  }
}
```

```css
.Basic-Text-Frame {
  margin: 10px;
}

p.SubEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h4.SmallEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -16px;
}

h1.Latin {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #166827;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h2.English {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #25408f;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h3.Num {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" ; charset="UTF-8">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>1-1</title>
  <link href="../../css/Book.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/Book.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="x1" xml:lang="en-US">
  <div class="buttons"> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction3()">bigger</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction4()">big</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction5()">normal</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction6()">small</button>
    <button
      class="button" onclick="myFunction7()">smaller</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction8()">fontWieght</button> </div>

  <div class="Basic-Text-Frame">

    <p class="SubEnglish">lorem <b>this is bold</b> ipsum lorem ipsum <b> this is also bold </b>ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <h4 class="SmallEnglish"><b class="char-style-override-4">d.</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsm lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</h4>
    <p class="SubEnglish"><span class="Normal char-style-override-4">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem im lorem psum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</span></p>
    <h1 id="toc_marker-1" class="Latin"><span class="char-style-override-3">I. </span>lorem ipsum<span class="char-style-override-3"></span></h1>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-1" class="English">A. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum (active pharmaceutical ingredient<span> </span>(API))</h2>
    <h3 class="Num"><b class="char-style-override-4">1.</b> lorem ipsum<b class="char-style-override-4"> This is bold</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum.</h3>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-3" class="English">C. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should learn about DRY principles, your code (css + js) could be done with about 15 lines instead of 100. Apart from that, make sure that the font is available with the font weight you've specified, I doubt it is

Comment: the html and css are auto generated by a program (I know it need cleaning but that not the issue here) and as you can see there is some text already in bold in the first <p> (the text says : this is bold)

Comment: `font-weight: 500;` in the CSS overrides the inherited `font-weight: 900;`. Instead of assigning CSS properties, consider toggling classes instead.

Comment: @xufox can you explain more, why it works for other style properties but not this one

Comment: remove `font-weight` from all css classes, then try again.

Comment: @MrT Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), and use the provided **Inspector** / **Elements** tab to see which styles are applied. [Toggle classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle#Examples).

Comment: @Sphinx can't do

Comment: @Xufox what i meant is can you provide a working example

Comment: `@Xufox`s comment to OP may be confusing. JavaScript trumps CSS and HTML inline styles, so the `font-weight` for `cols[0]` does become `'900'`. The child Elements of `cols[0]`, however, are still being styled by the CSS.

Comment: @PHPglue there is an [i] loop that should toggle all elements (as you can see for the other functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  changed the font-weight for `<div class="Basic-Text-Frame">`, but its each children have own font-weight, so it will overrides the inherited font-weight: 900;

Based on you can't change css, one solution is loop all children for `<div class="Basic-Text-Frame">`, then change their font-weight.

Below is one sample codes ( *I added one text='test', you can use your origial code to see what happened (it will be bolder successfully using your codes)*):

```js
function myFunction3() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-large";

  }
}

function myFunction4() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "large";

  }
}

function myFunction5() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "16px";

  }
}

function myFunction6() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "small";


  }
}

function myFunction7() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-small";
  }
}

function myFunction8() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");
  let _loopAll = function (obj) {
    let childs = obj.childNodes;
    for (let j=0; j < childs.length; j++) {
      if(childs[j].style) {
        childs[j].style.fontWeight = "bolder";
        _loopAll(childs[j])
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "bolder";
    _loopAll(cols[i])
  }
}
```

```css
.Basic-Text-Frame {
  margin: 10px;
}

p.SubEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h4.SmallEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -16px;
}

h1.Latin {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #166827;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h2.English {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #25408f;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h3.Num {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" ; charset="UTF-8">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>1-1</title>
  <link href="../../css/Book.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/Book.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="x1" xml:lang="en-US">
  <div class="buttons"> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction3()">bigger</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction4()">big</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction5()">normal</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction6()">small</button>
    <button
      class="button" onclick="myFunction7()">smaller</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction8()">fontWieght</button> </div>

  <div class="Basic-Text-Frame">
  Test
    <p class="SubEnglish">lorem <b>this is bold</b> ipsum lorem ipsum <b> this is also bold </b>ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <h4 class="SmallEnglish"><b class="char-style-override-4">d.</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsm lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</h4>
    <p class="SubEnglish"><span class="Normal char-style-override-4">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem im lorem psum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</span></p>
    <h1 id="toc_marker-1" class="Latin"><span class="char-style-override-3">I. </span>lorem ipsum<span class="char-style-override-3"></span></h1>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-1" class="English">A. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum (active pharmaceutical ingredient<span> </span>(API))</h2>
    <h3 class="Num"><b class="char-style-override-4">1.</b> lorem ipsum<b class="char-style-override-4"> This is bold</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum.</h3>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-3" class="English">C. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's working here, but i cant make it work in my original file. give a moment please

Comment: @PHPgluem plam my face, you are right... let me correct it.

Comment: @Sphinx problem solved. But if you have some extra time can you explain way it worked for one property (style.fontSize) without the extra loop for the children but not for the other property (style.fontWieght). Just an academic question

Comment: @MrT, you means why we have to loop children to implement font-weight, but other properties don't need ?

Comment: @Sphinx yes exactly

Comment: @MrT check this url [css-specificity-and-inheritance](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/css-specificity-and-inheritance/), it will tell you why font-weight of parent didn't apply to its children.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your CSS structure:

```
function goDeep(element, cssObj){
  var e = element.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for(var i=0,l=e.length; i<l; i++){
    for(var p in cssObj){
      e[i].style[p] = cssObj[p];
    }
  }
}
function myFunction8() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('Basic-Text-Frame'), css = {fontWeight:'900'};
  for(var i=0,l=cols.length; i<l; i++){
    goDeep(cols[i], css);
  }
}
```

Comment: @MrT the `goDeep` function will do what you expected `document.getElementsByClassName` to do (change the children elements), but I wouldn't recommend using such a function, you'll better use class names to target known elements for better control.

Comment: This would be a better answer with more explanation. The OP does not appear to have much experience with JavaScript.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I assume he would better learn javascript and some best practices instead of just copy-pasting codes, otherwise stackoverflow is not the place to ask

Comment: Actually, Stack Overflow is the place to ask, and answers should contain the appropriate amount of explanation. Otherwise, they are not helpful. See [answer], "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: I left a comment before posing this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

remove the font-weight: 500 from the parents' classes

```js
function myFunction3() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-large";

  }
}

function myFunction4() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "large";
    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "";
  }
}

function myFunction5() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "16px";
    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "";
  }
}

function myFunction6() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "small";
    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "";

  }
}

function myFunction7() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-small";
    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "";
  }
}

function myFunction8() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "900";
  }
}
```

```css
.Basic-Text-Frame {
  margin: 10px;
}

p.SubEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  /* font-weight: 500; */
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h4.SmallEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  /* font-weight: 500; */
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -16px;
}

h1.Latin {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #166827;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  /* font-weight: bold; /*
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h2.English {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #25408f;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h3.Num {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" ; charset="UTF-8">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>1-1</title>
  <link href="../../css/Book.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/Book.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="x1" xml:lang="en-US">
  <div class="buttons"> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction3()">bigger</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction4()">big</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction5()">normal</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction6()">small</button>
    <button
      class="button" onclick="myFunction7()">smaller</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction8()">fontWieght</button> </div>

  <div class="Basic-Text-Frame">

    <p class="SubEnglish">lorem <b>this is bold</b> ipsum lorem ipsum <b> this is also bold </b>ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <h4 class="SmallEnglish"><b class="char-style-override-4">d.</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsm lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</h4>
    <p class="SubEnglish"><span class="Normal char-style-override-4">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem im lorem psum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</span></p>
    <h1 id="toc_marker-1" class="Latin"><span class="char-style-override-3">I. </span>lorem ipsum<span class="char-style-override-3"></span></h1>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-1" class="English">A. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum (active pharmaceutical ingredient<span> </span>(API))</h2>
    <h3 class="Num"><b class="char-style-override-4">1.</b> lorem ipsum<b class="char-style-override-4"> This is bold</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum.</h3>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-3" class="English">C. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the problem is that you can't revert that unless you reload the page. and i'm working in a cordova project (hybrid mobile app uses web view so there is no reload button)

Comment: but the issue is this: shouldn't js override the css property (there is a font size deceleration in the css but the sizing functions still works fine ) isn't that strange?

Answer (score 0):

You should either remove the `font-weight` from `p.SubEnglish`, or change the font for the paragraph(p) elements with the JS code.
Your current JS changes the fontWeight only for the containing div, but the font-weight which has been set by your CSS for the `p.SubEnglish` is still "active", because the inner element's css rule is "stronger" than the outer container's rule. For example, if you have:

```
<div style="color:red">
  <p style="color:black">123456</p>
</p>
```

The text color will always be black, even if you change the div's style (unless you use `!important` which is not recommended)

I fix it for the paragraphs in your snippet, but same goes for other inner elements(header elements `<h1>`), so try to work on it.

```js
function myFunction3() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-large";

  }
}

function myFunction4() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "large";

  }
}

function myFunction5() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "16px";

  }
}

function myFunction6() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "small";


  }
}

function myFunction7() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontSize = "x-small";
  }
}

function myFunction8() {
  
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName("SubEnglish");

  for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {

    paragraphs[i].style.fontWeight = "900";
  }

  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");

  for (i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

    cols[i].style.fontWeight = "900";
  }
}
```

```css
.Basic-Text-Frame {
  margin: 10px;
}

p.SubEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h4.SmallEnglish {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -16px;
}

h1.Latin {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #166827;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h2.English {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #25408f;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

h3.Num {
  -epub-ruby-position: over;
  color: #231f20;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "WinSoft Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" ; charset="UTF-8">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>1-1</title>
  <link href="../../css/Book.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/Book.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="x1" xml:lang="en-US">
  <div class="buttons"> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction3()">bigger</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction4()">big</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction5()">normal</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction6()">small</button>
    <button
      class="button" onclick="myFunction7()">smaller</button> <button class="button" onclick="myFunction8()">fontWieght</button> </div>

  <div class="Basic-Text-Frame">

    <p class="SubEnglish">lorem <b>this is bold</b> ipsum lorem ipsum <b> this is also bold </b>ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    <h4 class="SmallEnglish"><b class="char-style-override-4">d.</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsm lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</h4>
    <p class="SubEnglish"><span class="Normal char-style-override-4">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem im lorem psum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</span></p>
    <h1 id="toc_marker-1" class="Latin"><span class="char-style-override-3">I. </span>lorem ipsum<span class="char-style-override-3"></span></h1>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-1" class="English">A. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum (active pharmaceutical ingredient<span> </span>(API))</h2>
    <h3 class="Num"><b class="char-style-override-4">1.</b> lorem ipsum<b class="char-style-override-4"> This is bold</b> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum.</h3>
    <h2 id="toc_marker-1-3" class="English">C. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have another classes that already bold (having property font-weight:900 in the original css) so i can't just delete the property

Comment: You don't have to delete it, you can change your JS code to take care of the <p> and <h1>\<h2> elements. Look how I changed your "problematic" function.

Comment: and document.getElementsByClassName (if working) should target the children elements, and i've included other functions using document.getElementsByClassName working and over riding css just fine. either we are missing somthing or it is a bug

Comment: that's not true at all... document.getElementsByClassName won't target any children elements, you should target the children classes(e.g. SubEnglish, SmallEnglish)

Comment: you can see the word "children" in the page you sent? I can't.
Children elements mean sub-elements, when you use `document.getElementsByClassName("Basic-Text-Frame");` expect only elements  with "Basic-Text-Frame" to be targeted, and not their CHILDREN elements (paragraphs and headers in your case)